# check string value using comma separate in xml file

Tags: php, xml, xpath

i have this type of xml file call is regin.xml:-

```
<root>
  <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="Game" parent_id="0">
    <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Activities" parent_id="1">
      <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Physical1" parent_id="2">
        <child_6 entity_id="6" value="Cricket" parent_id="3">
          <child_7 entity_id="7" value="One Day" parent_id="6"/>
        </child_6>
      </child_3>
      <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Test1" parent_id="1">
        <child_8 entity_id="8" value="Test At Abc" parent_id="4"/>
      </child_4>
      <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Test2" parent_id="1">
        <child_9 entity_id="9" value="Test At Xyz" parent_id="5"/>
      </child_5>
    </child_2>
</child_1>
</root>
```

this is one string:-

```
$activity = "One Day,Test At Abc,Test At Xyz";
```

here i want to check one by one comma separate value check in xml file.
i try this xpath.

```
$Rgn_id = $region->xpath("//*[@value = '$region1']/@entity_id");
```

if activity match in xml file then display there entity_id from xml file.
thanks...

this is my php try:-

```
<?php
$Activity = 'One Day,Test At Abc';
echo "$Activity";
$string = explode(",",$Activity);
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($string);
echo "</pre>";
$r = file_get_contents('final.xml');
$region = simplexml_load_string($r);
foreach($string as $Activity){
list($result) = $region->xpath("//*[contains('$Activity', (@value ,','))]/@entity_id");
$result = (string)$result;
echo "my activity id is = $result";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Passerby check my edited question i am add my php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
$value = ",$activity,"; // now $value is ",One Day,Test At Abc,Test At Xyz,"

$Rgn_id = $region->xpath("//*[contains('$value', concat(',', @value, ','))]/@entity_id");
```

Comment: please check my php code i am update...

Comment: You need to use the expression `concat(',', @value, ',')` as the second argument of the `contains` call, in your sample you have `contains('$Activity', (@value ,','))` which does not make sense. The idea is to check whether `,foo,` is contained in the list `,value 1,value 2, value 3,`.

Comment: i am try this:- `foreach($string as $Activity){
$result= $region->xpath("//*[contains('$Activity', (@value ,','))]/@entity_id");
echo "my activity id is = $result";
 }` its give me warning `SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid expression` ` SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed`

Comment: Well the XPath is not correct, either use the `foreach ($string as $act) { $result = $region->xpath("//*[@value = '$act']/@entity_id; .. }` or use the approach I outlined in your answer; that approach returns a list of nodes with a single XPath selection.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//*[contains(concat(',', $activity, ','), concat(',', @value, ','))]/@entity_id
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="activity" select="'One Day,Test At Abc,Test At Xyz'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vWanted" select=
     "//*[contains(concat(',', $activity, ','),
                   concat(',', @value, ',')
                   )
        ]/@entity_id"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$vWanted">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="Game" parent_id="0">
        <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Activities" parent_id="1">
            <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Physical1" parent_id="2">
                <child_6 entity_id="6" value="Cricket" parent_id="3">
                    <child_7 entity_id="7" value="One Day" parent_id="6"/>
                </child_6>
            </child_3>
            <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Test1" parent_id="1">
                <child_8 entity_id="8" value="Test At Abc" parent_id="4"/>
            </child_4>
            <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Test2" parent_id="1">
                <child_9 entity_id="9" value="Test At Xyz" parent_id="5"/>
            </child_5>
        </child_2>
    </child_1>
</root>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and then the values of the attributes that are selected as result of this evaluation are output**:

```
7 8 9
```

Comment: I think the poster has a PHP variable `$activity`, not an XPath variable. So the PHP string with an XPath expression should be `"//*[contains(',$activity,', concat(',', @value, ','))]/@entity_id"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I don't know PHP but you seem to put `$activity` as a string literal, which will actually represent a reference to a *XPath* variable named `activity`.  Most probably this isn't correct.

Comment: With PHP double quote limited string literals you can use PHP variables in the string and they will be replaced by their value. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double which says "The most important feature of double-quoted strings is .. that variable names will be expanded". With `$activity` being `$activity = "One Day,Test At Abc,Test At Xyz";` the string literal `"//*[contains(',$activity,', concat(',', @value, ','))]/@entity_id"` is expanded to `"//*[contains(',One Day,Test At Abc,Test At Xyz,', concat(',', @value, ','))]/@entity_id"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Oh, I see -- this is the reason why the OP in another question was specifying the variable part of an XPath expression in quotes ...